# Rest Api- get sales orders with authorizing only once

Tags: api, sales, rest-api, oauth

I have another website as admin panel which connects with magento store to fetch orders/products etc. 
I don't want to authorize every time I call the Api. I want the system will ask me for authorization only once. 
It might be possible if I could have a permanent oAuth access token or if somehow I can save the first token to the database for later use. 
Please give me your ideas.

Thanks